# Right using of PIVOT-statement in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have an audit table, part of data is looked like:

```
Id  ColumnName      Value   RowId
---------------------------------
1   EditCheckId     100     1
2   FieldData_Id    10      1
3   EditType        1       1
4   Outcome         True    1
5   EditCheckId     200     2
6   FieldData_Id    20      2
7   EditType        2       2
8   Outcome         False   2
9   EditCheckId     300     3
10  FieldData_Id    30      3
11  EditType        3       3
12  Outcome         True    3
```

and I want to construct such table groupping data by `RowId`

```
EditCheck_Id    FieldData_Id    EditType    Outcome
---------------------------------------------------
100             10              1           True
200             20              2           False               
300             30              3           True
```

I've tried the query:

```
select [EditCHeck_Id], [FieldData_Id], [EditType], [Outcome]
from
(
    select [ColumnName], [Value]
    from Audit a
) as [SourceTable]
pivot
(
    max([Value])
    for [ColumnName] in ([EditCHeck_Id], [FieldData_Id], [EditType], [Outcome])
) as [PivotTable];
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7af71/3

using PIVOT statement but there is only one row in answer. Where is my problem?

Comment: otherwise just use simple case condition..it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need some value to `GROUP BY` to make each of the rows distinct.  Typically, you would use a windowing function like `row_number()` to generate a unique sequenced number over your current `columnname`.  You can alter your query to the following:

```
select 
  [EditCheckId], 
  [FieldData_Id], 
  [EditType], 
  [Outcome]
from
(
  select [ColumnName], [Value],
    rn = row_number() over(partition by ColumnName order by id)
  from Audit a
) as [SourceTable]
pivot
(
    max([Value])
    for [ColumnName] in ([EditCheckId], [FieldData_Id], [EditType], [Outcome])
) as [PivotTable];
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7af71/14/0).

You could also use an aggregate function with a CASE expression to get the final result:

```
select 
  max(case when ColumnName = 'EditCheckId' then value end) [EditCheckId], 
  max(case when ColumnName = 'FieldData_Id' then value end) [FieldData_Id], 
  max(case when ColumnName = 'EditType' then value end) [EditType], 
  max(case when ColumnName = 'Outcome' then value end) [Outcome]
from
(
  select [ColumnName], [Value],
    rn = row_number() over(partition by ColumnName order by id)
  from Audit a
) d
group by rn;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7af71/15) Both give the result:

```
| EDITCHECKID | FIELDDATA_ID | EDITTYPE | OUTCOME |
|-------------|--------------|----------|---------|
|         100 |           10 |        1 |    True |
|         200 |           20 |        2 |   False |
|         300 |           30 |        3 |    True |
```

Answer (score 0):

You need something to distinguish the output rows, like for example your RowId

`pivot` does the grouping for you like so:

```
select [RowID], [EditCheckId], [FieldData_Id], [EditType], [Outcome]
from
(
    select [ColumnName], [Value], [RowId]
    from Audit a
) as [SourceTable]
pivot
(
    max([Value])
    for [ColumnName] in ([EditCheckId], [FieldData_Id], [EditType], [Outcome])
) as [PivotTable];
```

[edited Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7af71/22)